# ios not recognized

Tags: c++, file-io

I am working on a Windows VC++2008 program that does fileIO, and have hit an issue that is really weird. in my #include directives I have

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
```

and then I have a method that actually does the fileIO, but when I try to open the file like this:

```
std::ofstream Output;
Output.open("Output/log.txt", ios::out);
```

my intelisense allows it, and even has correct auto completes, but my compiler throws an error of:

```
1>c:...\engine\gsp420maincore\gsp420maincore\messagequeue.cpp(141) : error C2653: 'ios' : is not a class or namespace name
1>c:...\engine\gsp420maincore\gsp420maincore\messagequeue.cpp(141) : error C2065: 'out' : undeclared identifier
```

when I read about the ofstream.open() it stated that whether the file to be opened is for input, output, or both should be specified, but ios should be automatically included by any other iostream #include directive, and this problem is not corrected when I insert the:

```
#include <ios> // directive
```

the compiler has no complaints when I remove the second argument, but I know that I should try, and specify just in case I want to go in and read from a file as well as write to it. did I do something wrong?

Comment: Do you mean `std::ios` ?

Comment: yes, I did have to specify that. apparently because this file is compiled before the using namespace directive is given I have to specify that it resides in std

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to prefix it with `std::` and you haven't used `using namespace std;` (judging from the fact that you explicitly state the namespace for `std::ofstream`).

Try changing it to `std::ios::out`.

You should not need to `#include <ios>` manually.

Answer (score 2):

As already noted, you need `std::ios::out` -- only you really don't need it at all. When you open an `ofstream`, it opens for output by default (likewise, an `ifstream` gets opened for input by default). I'd also advise initializing the object at creation rather than creating a sort-of uninitialized stream, then opening it separately. Taking that into account, you get rather simpler bit of code:

```
std::ofstream Output("output/log.txt");
```